# How to install python iexfinance package on Anaconda?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

What is the exact command for installation of the python iexfinance package when using the Anaconda command prompt? Using the pip commands mentioned under "install" here does not work. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iexfinance

Answer (score 2):

It seems this package is not available through `anaconda` distribution.

Usually, besides the `conda install <package>` command, you have the alternative:

```
conda install -c conda-forge <package>
```

In your case, you can create a conda environment:

```
conda create --name <yourenv> python=3.5
```

then `source activate <yourenv>`,

and inside this environment you install your package, like so:

```
 pip3 install iexfinance
```

then proceed to install other packages with `conda install <package>` as you see fit.